# How to Remove Bottom Tab Border for Material Top Tabs in React Native Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am trying to use Material Top Tab Navigator and I cannot seem to get rid of the border vottom right below photos, videos and saved - I do not want a border there - what do I do? Below is everything I've tried...

[image]

```
 <ProfileTabs.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    tabBarIndicatorStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      borderWidth: 0,
      borderTopWidth: 0,
      borderBottomWidth: 0,
      borderColor: 'transparent',
    },
    tabBarStyle: {
      borderColor: 'transparent',
      borderWidth: 0,
      borderTopWidth: 0,
      borderBottomWidth: 0,
    },
    tabBarContentContainerStyle: {
      borderTopWidth: 0,
      borderColor: 'transparent',
    },
    tabBarItemStyle: {
      borderTopWidth: 0,
      borderWidth: 0,
      borderBottomWidth: 0,
      borderColor: 'transparent',
    },
  }}>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone struggling through this nonsense this is the answer.

```
 screenOptions={{
        tabBarStyle: {
          shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 0, // for iOS
          },
          elevation: 0,
          zIndex: 0,
        }}
```